# When encoding an image to base 64, the result is always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In my ReactJS project, I'm trying to store images in Firebase Realtime Database as a Base64 url and then convert back to an image on render.

(Note: I know that firestore has this built in, however it's too late to rewrite the code to implement the rest of the project on the platform.)

I take the file in via an input:

```
<input onChange={this.handleImageUpload} className="form-control" type="file" name="profilePicture" id="profilePicture" placeholder="Upload a profle picture"/>
```

Which runs the handleImageUpload() function:

```
  handleImageUpload = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const imageAsUrl = this.encodeImageFileAsUrl(e.target.files[0]);

    this.setState({
      profilePicture: imageAsUrl
    });

  }
```

Which calls the encodeImageAsUrl() function with the current file as input:

```
  encodeImageFileAsUrl = image => {
    const file = image;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const imageAsUrl = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log("Image as url = " + imageAsUrl)
    return imageAsUrl;

  }
```

The variable 'imageAsUrl' prints as 'undefined' and also note that any image I try is 1.2MB or less.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a event hook onload where you will get the data

```
encodeImageFileAsUrl = image => {
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
    const file = image;    

    const reader = new FileReader();
    //Like this
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        //Adding log to check result
        console.log(e.target.result);
        resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    const imageAsUrl = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
} 

handleImageUpload = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const imageAsUrl = await this.encodeImageFileAsUrl(e.target.files[0]);

    this.setState({
      profilePicture: imageAsUrl
    });

  }
```

Comment: I understand the logic on what you're doing, but the provided code is still printing as undefined...

Comment: Try to debug whether you are getting data in `e.target.result`

Comment: I have updated the code with log statement

Comment: e.target.result actually does contain the base64 encoded data. I can paste the data into an online image converter and it shows me the right image. Should I be setting the state to e.target.result or should it be imageAsUrl?

Comment: Try testing if you are getting data in `imageAsUrl` before setting state